# MAMP Pro on Windows, edit php.ini

Tags: windows, mamp, mamp-pro, php-ini

I just installed MAMP Pro on a Windows 10 machine but I can't seem to update my php.ini file correctly.

I set the php version to 5.6.0 and then found the php.ini file (C://MAMP/conf/php5.6.0/php.ini) and adjusted the max_upload_size and max_post_size to 200M but that does not get reflected in phpmyadmin. So I can't upload my sql file.

I have restarted the server several times double checked that file (the values are persistent) but phpmyadmin still shows a max upload size of 32M.

What do I need to do to change those values ?

Comment: php -i/phpinfo() will tell you which ini file(s) were processed at startup. make sure you're modifying the right one.

Answer (score 1):

MAMP holds configuration files in C:\MAMP\conf\

MAMP PRO holds configuration files in Users directory.

For example:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\conf\

But to preserve state of changed php.ini file for php version you're using you should use Template feature. 
You can edit these templates from the MAMP PRO menu item File > Edit template.